# Proof on Banach-Mazur distance

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Suppose $X,Y$ normed vector spaces with $dimX=dimY=n $. We know that X and Y are 
We define the Banach-Mazur distance between X,Y as:

$d(X,Y)=\inf \{ \|T\|\|T^{-1}\|:T\in GL(X,Y) \} $, where $GL(X,Y)$  is the space of all linear isomorphisms.

I want to prove that $d(X,Y)=\min \{ \|T\|\|T^{-1}\|:T\in GL(X,Y) \} $.
The proof goes:

From the definition of infimum we know that there a exist a sequence of isomorphisms $S_m :X \rightarrow Y$ s.t. $|S_m||S^{-1}_{m}| \rightarrow d(X,Y)$

Now we set the sequence $T_m=|S^{-1}_{m}|S_m$ \

My book says that $|T^{-1}_{m}|=1$ but i can't figure out why.

Comment: $T_m^{-1}=\frac{1}{|S_m^{-1}|}S_m^{-1}$, hence $|T_m^{-1}|=\frac{1}{|S_m^{-1}|}|S_m^{-1}|=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define $T_m=|S_m^{-1}|S_m$, then $|T_m^{-1}|=(1/|S_m^{-1}|)|S_m^{-1}|=1$.

Now, to prove the statement, it is sufficiently noting that $GL(X,Y)$ is also a finite dimensional normed space, so the unit ball is compact. Done!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).